# Compiling ODE code in Linux

Tags: linux, compilation, ode-library

I have downloaded ode-0.11.1 and I am able to compile source code by modifying the Makefile provided with the demos, but I can't figure out how to manually compile and link the code I need as a standalone.

I tried probing at the Makefile and substituting the macros manually, as well as running it and checking the output.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

OpenDE, or ODE, is configured with GNU autoconf/automake tools.
This means that you need to invoke ./configure before you can build the package.
To see all the options, use:

```
$ ./configure --help
```

An invokation to ./configure will often need a target where to install to.
A typical invokation would look like this:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-trimesh=opcode
$ make install
```

This will install OpenDE in your home directory.
If you omit the --prefix argument, the default /usr/local will be used, and you will need root permissions to install.
The example invokation will also include support for triangle meshes using OPCODE.